# Symfony3 Assetic ignoring output directory

Tags: css, symfony, assetic

I have this in my base layout twig file

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite' output='compiled/css/main.css'
    'css/bootstrap.min.css'
    'css/noty.css'
    'css/noty-bs.css'
    'css/styles.css'
%}
```

Nothing odd here. But when using `assetic:dump` its creating the files as expected in `compiled/css` along with the `compiled/css/main.css` file.

But its also placing a load of files in my main `css` directory.

See here, the `compiled` dir is right. But it should not be placing anything in my `css` dir? Why is this happening? The files is red should not be there because I have provided an `output` for `stylesheets`.

[image]

My assetic config is

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
    bundles:
        - AppBundle
        - MemberBundle
```

Comment: Are you use there are not files from a previous command ?

Comment: If I delete them then they come back each time

Comment: Weird, i don't have the problem it outputs in compiled. What command do you launch ? Do you specify an env ?

Comment: No env. I tried `assetic:watch` which acted accordingly. Then I tried `assetic:dump` again and its worked as expected. No extra output to `css` Very odd.

Comment: Assetic live it last hours, we should another build tools.

Comment: You think it was cached?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I experienced this duplicating of files:

> But when using assetic:dump its creating the files as expected in compiled/css along with the compiled/css/main.css file.

I found clearing the cache (`php app/console cache:clear -v`) and then re-running dump worked to rectify this.

(NB: As with comments on the question, we are also moving away from assetic too).